# Dynamic number of fields in Joomla module

Tags: joomla, module, field

I just started to work with Joomla 3 and I'm trying to create a simple module for a jQuery based gallery.

I have 2 simple form fields:

```
<field name="img_src_1" type="text" size="60" default="" label="" description="" />
<field name="img_name_1" type="text" size="60" default="" label="" description="" />
```

Is there any way to add more images fields without duplicating those two lines with different names? (img_src_2,img_src_3...)

It will be very nice for the user to choose how many images he would like, without hard-coding it.

Comment: why don't you tell the module to get all the images from a specific folder such as `root/images/my_slider` ? the way you're currently doing it, is defining each image source and name as parameters.

Comment: @Lodder What if I want to add a title or a short description for each image? how can I achieve that?

Comment: In that case, you could develop a small component and add the images along with the titles and descriptions through there. Some slideshows use articles instead. In the end, the choice is up to you. It depends how much time you're willing to spend on it and which you prefer

Comment: Or create a custom field type.